# Spinner updating only on user actions

Tags: java, android, user-interface, spinner, android-adapter

I have IconText that has image and text views inside it, both class and xml.

I then populate the Spinner inside of the MainActivity with these IconTexts, using extended BaseAdapter (IconTextAdapter) as adapter.

Now, IconText works fine (shows as it should).
Spinner however doesn't.

1. When I start the app, it shows the first IconText as it should.
2. When I open the choose dialog, everything is showing as it should.
3. When I select another item, the choose dialog collapses and spinner displays no IconText (ie. only "arrow down" for opening choose dialog).

I can still open the choose dialog and choose another.
I've noticed that if I exit from app (return button, not really quiting the app) and enter again that the proper IconText is shown.

I guess that the fault lies with the adapter?
I will try avoiding posting a lot of code [:

IconText.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/it_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/home"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/it_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20sp"
        android:text="ABC"
        android:textColor="@color/black_overlay"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

IconText.java

```
public class IconText {

    static LayoutInflater inflator;

    public ImageView icon;
    public TextView text;
    public View view;

    public IconText(String title, int icon_id){
        Log.d("IconText", "Create");
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.icon_text, null);

        text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.it_text);
        icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.it_image);

        text.setText(title);
        icon.setImageResource(icon_id);
    }

    public static void initInflator(Context context){
        if(inflator != null) return;
        Log.d("IconText", "Init inflator");
        inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

IconTextAdapter.java

```
public class IconTextAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter{

    public ArrayList<IconText> items;

    public IconTextAdapter(){
        super();
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return items.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return items.get(position).view.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return items.get(position).view;
    }
}
```

MainActivity, relevant code

```
void initFilter(){
        Log.d("MainAction", "Find Filter");
        filter = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.filter);
        Log.d("MainAction", "Create Adapter");
        IconTextAdapter adapter = new IconTextAdapter();

        Log.d("MainAction", "Create items");
        for(int i=0; i<ETypes.names.length; i++){
            IconText it = new IconText(ETypes.names[i], ETypes.icons[i]);
            adapter.items.add(it);
        }
        Log.d("MainAction", "Setting adapter");
        filter.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

ETypes names[string] and icons[id] are static.
Inflator is initialized succesfully.

I haven't worked much in Android. If it were Java/Swing, I guess I would just call a redraw or something.

I know there are some bad practices here (all public variables, and so on). This code is still in early prototype stage, it will be fixed soon. I'm not looking for optimization, just for the solution to my problem.

Update 1:
So I saw I didn't implement **getDropDownView** so I did, the same code as getView (no need to post it?).

Also I made an experiment: At the end of IconText contrusctor I added

```
view = text
```

And it works just fine (showing only text).

I guess this pinpoints that the problem originates from custom view?

Update 2:

Did another experiment with IconText, setting `view = icon;` and it doesn't behave as it should, ie. it behaves like it's a custom view.

Comment: Can you post a simple project at github with that behavior?

Comment: I think I figured it out... Just need a bit time to test things. If I'm wrong I will post it to github, but I want to avoid that as it is not a personal project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't really solve this specific bug, but it solves my problem.

[Custom Image and Text View in Spinner Solution.](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-Spinner-customized-to-show-image-and-text.htm)

Comment: Glad to see you solved this. It will be better if you explain where BUG

Comment: Certainly on the getView and getDropDownView methods. I have a lot on my plate, if/when I have the time I will pinpoint the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

To update the list you must call 
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

after adding new data to your adapter

Please refer to the following

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Hmmm, where should I call it? I create all the data before setting the adapter...

Comment: you can call it where you are handling your event when replacing your subject with new one ... happy coding bro :)